# How can I install Google Map Api to my new Android Device?

Tags: android, google-maps

I got a G7 Desire recently that didn't has Google Map Api Lib in it.
When I installed an app that use google map api on my phone, the adb console showed INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY error. 
So how can I install Google Map Api to my new G7?

PS. Is there a device list of what android devices do not have Google Map Api Lib?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have an Android phone (HTC Desire for Chinese market) that is not Google-branded. This means that there are no Google apps on it: no market, no gmail, no maps, etc..

You need to root your phone and then search for Google apps on various forums. Try http://www.xda-developers.com/

**Beware:** Google apps on Android are bundled with the phone and the license is only for this phone. Google does not offer this apps for non-google branded phones. All such apps are pirated and as such are illegal. Just so that you know..

**P.S.** All Google branded devices have "with Google (TM)" written on them. If there is no such sigh than there are no Google apps on this device. Don't be so sure about non-brandname devices sold in China. Anything is possible there.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are writing an application of your own you don't need to actually have the API. You only need to install Google Maps ( go to the market ) on your phone and all other apps should work with it fine.

Comment: Thank you for replay. I am actually writing an application of myself that use the google map view.

Comment: Then you need to get the google map API, however you wouldn't need that on your phone, you're supposed to develop on a workstation with an Android emulator. You can use Eclipse with the Android SDK.

Comment: Yes. I have a workstation with an Android emulator. And my app works fine in the Android emulator. However when I install the apk by the command "adb install myapp.apk". the error INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY came up. I think it is because there's no Google Map Api on my new device. So How can I install the api to my phone?

Comment: Oh, now I see what you mean. Well, it's not a missing library on the phone, it is a problem with a library on your API... Possibly you have an older version of the Android SDK or the Google Maps API?? Check those and get back to us.

Comment: My phone's Android version is 2.2. And the kernel version is 2.6.32.15-g5d39305. I am using "Google APIs 2.1-update (API level 7)" on my workstation. My app works fine in the emulator. But it can not be installed on my phone with the error INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY.

Comment: Just some more info about the error: logcat shows "E/PackageManager(  515): Package <XXX> requires unavailable shared library com.google.android.maps; failing!" It happens on my new noname Chinese Android 4.2.1 device, though it has Google Play app installed, and I did install Google Maps from it, but it doesn't help. Device Manager from ASDK shows that the device doesn't have Google API, and I guess it is the reason why Google Play says "Your device is not compatible with this version" when I try to install it via store.

Answer (score -1):

Download the Google Maps app from the MarketPlace

Comment: Thank you for reply. Also there's not the android market in my new phone. I have installed Google Map by using Applanet. but INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY is still there. I think may be it is because I need Google Map Api instead of Google Map application.

Comment: Yes if building your app use the Google API's version!

Comment: Right, I have pointed my app's target to Google API and the app runs fine in the android emulator. When I install it to my phone by adb install myapp.apk. the INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY error came up. I think it is because there's no Google API LIB on my phone. So how can I intall the lib to my new phone?