# i had develop application in Google API 2.1 and if i run on android2.2 without Google API then what happen?

Tags: android, api

i had develop application in Google API 2.1 and if i run on android2.2 without Google API then what happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably ClassNotFoundException.

Update:

It seems the system will already complain during app installation, that a library is missing: [How can I install Google Map Api to my new Android Device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4297327/how-can-i-install-google-map-api-to-my-new-android-device)